# How does the new move "Foul Play" work?

Tags: pokemon-series

The game (and [this site](http://www.psypokes.com/dex/techdex/492/general)) both say that the base power of Foul Play is 95, but that the base power also increases with the target's Attack stat.

What exactly does this mean?  How is the base power of this move calculated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attack has a base power of 95, but instead of using the user's Attack stat to calculate damage, it uses the opponent's Attack stat. ([Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Foul_Play_%28move%29))

Comment: Oh, wow. That's weird.

Comment: Yeah. With the exception of Sabeleye and the Houndour family, the Pokémon that can learn the move have great Attack stats, so there isn't really a point of using it over, say, Crunch. (Unless of course you know you're facing a Pokémon with an even better Attack stat than your own, but it's really situation and unreliable.)

Comment: It basically acts as if the target did a 95 power attack to themselves. Would be awesome against Slaking!

Comment: Krookodile, in particular, is pretty bad choice to have Foul Play on. There are people who beat him in Attack... but when you have Intimidate? It just... doesn't work...

Comment: This might be interesting to use on a moveset with Swagger...

Comment: It also might have a side use on a Special Sweeper or Defensive Wall (assuming they learn it).